# WP_Query() and get_posts() can't handle over a thousand posts?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

So I have a search function that just fetch custom posts and return them as a list.

```
function search() {

   // post query args
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    // markup
    $markup = '<ul>';

    //the loop
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        $markup .= '<li></li>';
    } wp_reset_postdata();

    $markup .='</ul>';

    echo $markup;
}
```

This works with under a hundred posts but with over a thousand posts, it doesn't. It just throws an error. If I switch to get_posts(), the same thing happens. Is there another way I could this?

Comment: Is the error a timeout error?

Comment: @kaiser: That's another problem actually because our admin has not enabled error reporting in our server. Could you tell me if this should work and that the issue is on the server config or something? Because I can confirm that my function perfectly works on smaller number of posts.

Comment: if it's not timing out, you're likely running out of memory

Comment: No error reporting? Stop working. Senseless task.

Comment: @milo as an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not timing out, you're likely running out of memory.